# Calculating the appropriate inset value for legends automatically

Tags: r, plot, legend

Is it possible to obtain the appropriate value of `inset` automatically so that the left corner of legend will always be just outside of the top right corner of plot?

In the plot below I had to try several values for `inset` manually. It would be nice to not have to do it manually since I have to make multiple plots.

```
graphics.off()
windows(width = 5, height = 5)
set.seed(42)
par(mar = c(5,5,1,10))
plot(rnorm(50,15,5), rnorm(50,15,3),
                xlim = c(0,30), ylim = c(5,25),
                pch = 19, col = c("red","blue"))

par(xpd = TRUE)
legend("topright", inset = c(-.80, 0),
                pch = 19, col = c("red","blue"),
                legend = c("LEGEND 1","Second Legend"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the `plot` call, before adding the `legend`, use `par("usr")`* to extract the coordinates of the plotting region.

Then, instead of positioning the legend using a 'keyword' and `inset`, use `x` and `y` with the top-right coordinates of the plotting region obtained from `par("usr")`. Adjust `x` with a suitable coefficient.

```
coord <- par("usr")
legend(x = coord[2] * 1.05, y = coord[4],
       pch = 19, col = c("red", "blue"),
       legend = c("LEGEND 1", "Second Legend"))
```

[image]

---

And just for fun, a more convoluted alternative.

After `plot`ting, call `legend` with position `topright`, but without plotting it to the device (`plot = FALSE`), and assign it to an object.

Extract the left `x` and the top `y` coordinate of the legend box, and its width (see *Value* section in `?legend`), to be used in `x` and `y` in `legend`:

```
leg <- legend("topright", pch = 19, col = c("red", "blue"),
              legend = c("LEGEND 1", "Second Legend"),
              plot = FALSE)

legend(x = (leg$rect$left + leg$rect$w) * 1.05, y = leg$rect$top,
       pch = 19, col = c("red", "blue"),
       legend = c("LEGEND 1", "Second Legend"))
```

[image]

---

*From `?par`

> `usr` A vector of the form `c(x1, x2, y1, y2)` giving the extremes of the user coordinates of the plotting region.

The position calculations that are made when `inset` parameter(s) have been specified, are in fact based on `par("usr")` (see line 188-199 in the [`legend` code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/graphics/R/legend.R)).